# Bazel Remote Cache not working with certificates/TLS

Tags: https, grpc, tls1.2, bazel

I'm runnig Bazel remote cache from https://github.com/buchgr/bazel-remote inside docker, by runnig the following commands to start the **http** and **grpc** server:

```
docker pull buchgr/bazel-remote-cache
docker run -u 1000:1000 -v /path/to/cache/dir:/data -p 9093:8080 -p 9094:9092 buchgr/bazel-remote-cache
```

So far I can run some tests from my client by running one of the following commands:

```
bazelisk test  --remote_cache=http://<SERVER_IP>:<SERVER_PORT> <TEST_TARGET>
bazelisk test  --remote_cache=grpc://<SERVER_IP>:<SERVER_PORT> <TEST_TARGET>
```

But when I put my server to run over **TLS** by adding the following flags to the server invocation:

```
-v /path/to/certificate_authority:/etc/bazel-remote/ca_cert
-v /path/to/server_cert:/etc/bazel-remote/server_cert
-v /path/to/server_key:/etc/bazel-remote/server_key
--tls_ca_file=/etc/bazel-remote/ca_cert
--tls_cert_file=/etc/bazel-remote/server_cert
--tls_key_file=/etc/bazel-remote/server_key
```

Although I created a root **CA** certificate to sign both my **server**'s and **clients**' certificates, I'm not able to access my server via **https** or **grpcs**. The following errors are being raised for **https**:

```
avax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General OpenSslEngine problem


sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target


sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

And the following for **grpcs**:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General OpenSslEngine problem

java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present

ERROR: Failed to query remote execution capabilities: General OpenSslEngine problem
```

Is this problem related to the fact the root **CA** certificate is self signed itself or am I doing something else stupid?

I used the very same commands from the following link: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/test/testdata/test_tls_certificate/README.md

Comment: Can you add the commands you used to generate the root CA and client+server keys+certificates? Also, wild guess on the problem: your tls_cert_file just has the leaf certificate, without an intermediate certificate necessary to form a chain.

Comment: Of course. I used the very same commands from the following link that I'm going to add to the post: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/test/testdata/test_tls_certificate/README.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **grpcs**, your problem is the hostname the client is using doesn't match the certificate. When I connect to `localhost` (like those directions default to), it works:

```
bazel test --remote_cache=grpcs://localhost:9094 --tls_client_certificate=/path/to/client.crt --tls_client_key=/path/to/client.pem --tls_certificate=/path/to/ca.crt //...
```

But if I switch to `127.0.0.1`, it fails like you're seeing. If you have a hostname, changing `SERVER_CN` to match it should work. IP addresses are a bit trickier though, because you have to use a subject alternative name to tie the certificate to the IP. The most direct way I know is creating a file `extensions.cnf` with this line:

```
subjectAltName=IP:<SERVER_IP>
```

and then using that file with `-extfile` when generating the certificate. You can just add this command at the end of the directions to generate a new certificate including it:

```
openssl x509 -req -passin pass:1111 -days 358000 -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out server.crt -extfile extensions.cnf
```

I don't think bazel supports client certificates with **https**. You can fix the problem you're running into using a custom truststore, but I can't figure out how to pass the client certificate. The only part of the code that uses that option looks like it's GRPC-specific. The documentation does not make that clear though...

A few more x509 basics: CA certificates are usually self-signed, because as the root of trust clients don't care how they're signed. The server certificate generated by those directions is not self-signed, contrary to the echo statement. Clients validate that the certificate they receive from the server matches the entity they're attempting to connect to (so that a certificate issued for yourwebsite.com can't be used to pretend to be google.com, for example). The CN is one field that can tie those together, subjectAltName is an extension that can be used to tie a certificate to multiple entities in various formats.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @Brian. I was also reading some more after posting this question here and everything you say makes lots of sense. I would like to be able to upvote twice. Just some more tests and I'll probably be back to accept this answer.

Comment: My problem is solved man. Thanks for your time. Now I'm running the following command using hostname instead of IP address: `bazelisk test  --remote_cache=grpc://<SERVER_HOSTNAME>:<SERVER_PORT> <TEST_TARGET>`